# Como consumir Json no Android?

Tags: android, json

Como faço para consumir um Json no Android?

Comment: Trata se de webService?

Comment: Pode ser http também.

Comment: Como assim "utilizar"? Ler um atributo? Criar? Converter em objeto? Se você tornar a sua pergunta mais específica, terá maiores chances de receber uma boa resposta e de ajudar quem mais ter a mesma dúvida no futuro.

Comment: Veja também : http://kobjects.org/ksoap2/index.html, pode ajudar te

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Use a lib IOn(REST) que fornece um JSONObject e você pode fazer Requisições POST, GET, PUT e etc.

**Primeiro adicione a dependencia no app**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
}
```

**Para ler e mandar um json:**

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
json.addProperty("foo", "bar");

    Ion.with(context)
.load("http://example.com/post")
.setJsonObjectBody(json)
.asJsonObject()
.setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
   @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
        // do stuff with the result or error
    }
});
```

Usando callback, ou seja não ficara blocado até a resposta chegar, e seu retorno tem que ser tratado assincronamente.

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
json.addProperty("foo", "bar");

 JsonObject json = Ion.with(context)
.load("http://example.com/post")
.setJsonObjectBody(json)
.asJsonObject()//aqui voce define o tipo do retorno
.get();
```

Usando o get o metodo ficara blocado até receber a resposta e pode ser tratado sincronamente.

**Para tratar o retorno em um JsonObject:**

```
json.get("nomeDaKey");
```

Link para mais informações da Lib:https://github.com/koush/ion

Comment: Você tem um exemplo de como trabalhar o retorno do json? Supomos que ele retorne id e name, como trabalharia isso no onCompleted?

Comment: Da sim, já editei a resposta. Espero que te ajude.

Comment: Oi, como adiciono essa biblioteca no Android Studio?

Comment: entra no bluild.gradle do seu projeto e adiciona esse codigo nas dependencies "compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'" @LuizaCH

Comment: vai sim @LuizaCH

Comment: Por favor, não estou conseguindo manipular o retorno dele. No onCompleted, como posso pegar cada valor do json neste formato [{"id":"1","nome":"XXX","cidade":"XXXXXXX"},{"id":"2","nome":"XXXX","cidade":"XXXXXXXXXX"}]